# Postpone loading an image that is not visible on initial view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, image

I am trying to figure out how to optimize a duplication of an image. Basically I have the same image in four different sections. However, the sections are controlled with toggle tabs, so only one shows at a time.

Is there a way for the browser to not load the image until the tab is clicked or for the browser to load the image once, rather than four times and then to just echo it?

I thought of doing something just like the following and then echoing it, but won't the image still load four times?:

```
$target = '<img src="../images/target.jpg" ';
```

I am fine with the image loading multiple times, but not on page load, to allow for reducing the initial page load for the user.

If this is confusion at all, please ask for more information.

Comment: if it's the exactly same picture, it should be loaded only once, and then used from the cache

Comment: @ThomasAltmann How would I do something like that? The only thing is I want to use different `alt` titles.

Comment: then just echo it four times with different alt-texts, the caching is done by the browser/server itself (unless you change that). You can watch the network-traffic with the chrome dev-tools for example, and you should see that the image isn't actually loaded 4 times

Comment: the browser will not load the image four times unless you specifically set a header to tell the browser not to cache it. the browser will load the image once and then use the same image every other time that image is referenced. if you monitor the "net" tab in developer tools you will only see the image loaded once.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This helped.

Comment: If the image is different, you can always set the attribute as a data source and swap the image src when the tab is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A Useful Tutorial And Explanation](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html)

*The same image will only get loaded once, the browsers doesn't load an image anew every single time the source gets mentioned, even when the alt is different*

## PHP

With PHP you can only influence what HTML is send to the browser. But, you want the browser to load your image after the rest of the page. With PHP, you cannot tell te browser to do so, it treats all HTML in the same way.

## JS

To do the trick, the image can be loaded in after the page has been loaded. Since the image is not visible yet on the homepage, this does not matter.

To make the browser load in the image afterwards you can give an `<img>` a fake src and an attribute containing the real source, like so:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="THE_LINK_TO_YOUR_IMAGE">
```

`data-src` now contains the real link to your image.

With the following JS you can then change out the data-src attribute to become the src attribute, after the page has loaded. The image will then load immediately after the page has finished loading:

### JS

```
<script>
    function init() {
        var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
            if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
                imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
    } } }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

The JS should come just before the last body tag, to further decrease loading time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: its looks like vanilla script and not jquery